# Títulos de perguntas devem começar com letra maiúscula?

Tags: debate

Volta e meia os títulos das perguntas que eu faço são editados para começarem com letra maiúscula. Existe alguma regra quanto a isso? Alguma recomendação ou algum padrão?

Comment: Parece que tem uma regra sobre isso sim: https://www.normaculta.com.br/maiuscula/ e http://portugues.uol.com.br/gramatica/letras-maiusculas-minusculas-circunstancias-uso.html Tem regras sobre acentos, enfim tem um monte de regra http://www.buscape.com.br/novissima-gramatica-da-lingua-portuguesa-novo-acordo-ortografico-domingos-paschoal-cegalla-8504014118

Comment: Entendi... mas acredito que isso não responda exatamente. Por estas regras imagino que o título poderia ser inteiro em maiúsculas também, enfim... Acho que o site possui uma convenção, que não está totalmente clara, visto que diversas formas são aceitas.

Comment: `Por estas regras imagino que o título poderia ser inteiro em maiúsculas também` Não consigo imaginar como é possível concluir isso. A convenção é que o textos devem ser claros e corretos. Sempre que alguém vê algo postado com erros ortográficos ou gramaticais e souber e estiver disposto a consertar, apessoa conserta.

Comment: *Títulos de livros, que podem estar totalmente em maiúsculas ou apenas com maiúscula inicial. Deverão ser escritos em itálico* Está no primeiro link que você passou, não sei em qual quadro um título de pergunta se encaixa, achei essa a melhor opção dentre as possíveis.

Comment: No final ainda tem: *O Acordo Ortográfico possibilita que áreas específicas sigam regras próprias relativamente ao uso de maiúsculas, desde que reconhecidas internacionalmente e criadas por entidades científicas ou normalizadoras.*

Comment: Isso não é um título de um livro, é uma frase como outra qualquer. O que quer dizer ali é que existem casos que pode haver um motivo para fazer exceção, pode ser por uma marca, um termo técnico necessário que é descrito como minúsculo sempre, e coisas deste tipo. Não é que cada um faz do jeito que quiser. Precisa ter justificativa para fazer exceção. Se você puder mostrar que algum caso é uma exceção, que é algo reconhecido internacionalmente por entidades científicas ou normalizadoras, então estará certo gramaticalmente.

Comment: Não acho que seja uma frase como qualquer outra, senão não seria um título. Claro que não é cada um faz como quer... Gostaria de saber se existe alguma convenção, mesmo. Na Wikipedia por exemplo, vi que teve uma votação para decidir se usavam `Títulos Assim` ou `Títulos assim`. O próprio SOPt usa letras minúsculas em alguns títulos (veja por exemplo as abas da página de participação dos usuários).   Mas está entendido: para perguntas aqui é melhor usar maiúscula (na primeira letra do título).

Comment: Se usarmos a analogia de um livro, "Stack Overflow em Português" e os títulos das perguntas são como capítulos ou seções dentro do livro. Da última vez que eu consultei regras de capitalização, o mais comum era "Capitalizar assim" e não "Capitalizar Assim", pois o segundo incorre em diversos problemas com palavras que são nomes pessoais, que possuem hífen ou apenas uma letra. Estou excluindo desta análise exceções puramente estéticas.

Comment: Dei uma boa olhada pelo site, e me parece bem claro que o essencial está correto, que é a inicial em maiúscula, e quando é explicitamente um formato de pergunta, com interrogação no final. Não consegui notar essa coisa de "cada um põe como quer". Se o autor do post esbarrou em alguma exceção, basta apontar, que podemos corrigir.

Comment: Relacionada: [Devo editar o título de uma pergunta a fim de torná-la mais objetiva?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2376/4808)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Pergunta simples

A convenção da comunidade é que o título de uma pergunta deveria ser uma simples... *pergunta*.

Neste caso, a regra básica do Português de iniciar com uma maiúscula e terminar com um ponto de interrogação parece ser consenso.

## Título da página

Claro que algumas vezes acaba passando alguns títulos que apenas fazem referência ao assunto, tal como "*Responder Perguntas com finalidades obscuras*" ao invés de, por exemplo, "*Devemos responder perguntas com finalidades obscuras?*".

Isto seria como um título da página ou de um artigo ou tópico qualquer. Portanto, o consenso parece ser de iniciar com maiúscula, mas sem ponto final.

## Consideração

Note que eu usei as palavras *consenso* e *convenção*. Não há uma regra, até onde eu sei, que seja imposta,  nem somos obrigados a seguir uma norma específica da língua portuguesa. Porém, o que apresentei acima parece ser considerado o melhor para o site, salvo possíveis raras exceções.

## O que fazer agora?

Minha sugestão é:

- Procure escrever conforme a convenção apresentada aqui.
- Recomende o mesmo para os demais usuários, com educação, quando necessário.
- Quando, voluntariamente, for melhorar uma pergunta e tiver a oportunidade, edite o conteúdo conforme as regras da língua.
- Evite votos para fechar ou negativos se o problema é são apenas algumas maiúsculas ou minúsculas, um ponto de interrogação, etc.

Comment: Gosto muito dessa resposta. O uso cauteloso e intencional de "consenso" e "convenção", e a afirmação explícita de que não há obrigatoriedade alguma de se seguir normas específicas da língua portuguesa no site fazem completo sentido. Não é porque há uma norma que qualquer desvio à norma deva ser reprimido ou rechaçado, sob o risco de pedantismo extremo que não faz bem algum à quem participa ou ao site.

Comment: @Gabe e utluiz mas então e se toda a gente começar agora a escrever os títulos em caps ou só em minusculas, edita-se, não se edita. Eu fiquei na dúvida. Eu entendo a não obrigatoriedade, mas dizer isso assim não vai criar uma onda de cada um faz o que quer e não me editem nada?

Comment: @JorgeB. Adicionei um tópico para resolver esse possível mal-entendido.

Comment: @utluiz boa sugestão :)

Comment: @JorgeB. Concordo totalmente com as sugestões do utluiz, mesmo não acreditando nem um pouco que dizer que não existe nenhuma regra absoluta vá causar alguma espécie de caos no site, com cada um fazendo o que quer sem motivo algum.

Comment: @Gabe claro que foi exagerado, era só para entenderem o meu ponto de vista.

Answer (score 11):

Confesso que estou com dificuldades de entender o objetivo da sua pergunta. Você está querendo saber se pode continuar iniciando as suas perguntas com minúsculas ou não, é isso? Se for isso, parece que [já sabe a resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5577/t%c3%adtulos-de-perguntas-devem-come%c3%a7ar-com-letra-mai%c3%bascula#comment21085_5577): *claro que não é "cada um faz como quer"*.

Iniciar títulos com maiúsculas é uma convenção à qual somos todos expostos desde os primeiros contatos com a palavra escrita. Se aqui é um ambiente colaborativo, adotar convenções assim tão comuns me parece um caminho óbvio. As alternativas seriam o "cada um faz como quer" (anticolaborativo por definição), ou decretar que aqui os títulos sempre começam com minúsculas (nada intuitivo, convenhamos).

Isso não quer dizer que um título com inicial minúscula nunca possa existir. Mas se não houver um bom motivo para começar com minúscula, ele tenderá a ser editado pela comunidade cedo ou tarde. Um exemplo de bom motivo é quando a pergunta começa com palavra reservada de linguagem de programação, e essa palavra começa com minúscula. Considerando a natureza do site, justificativas técnicas para essas escolhas tendem a ser bem aceitas. Justificativas estéticas, acho difícil, mas quem sabe. Em resumo: se quiser emplacar um título assim, vai ter que argumentar e convencer o pessoal.

Comment: Sim, é isso mesmo. Aparentemente sou o único que não acha isso tão óbvio assim...

Comment: Eu concordo que tem vários casos que não são óbvios, como os elementos de interface do site que você citou. E mesmo títulos, em outros contextos, existem começando em minúsculas aos montes na internet e nas ruas. Mas é que aqui, se for olhar, a esmagadora maioria dos títulos começa com maiúscula. É uma convenção orgânica, nunca isso foi debatido ou decidido. Por isso chamei de "óbvio".